# numberOfLines in UILabel is not woking after use NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: ios, swift, string, colors, uilabel

i am doing multi-color Text in UILabel. it works well. but problem i got that, i can show multi-line in UIlabel. it means numberOfLine property is not work.

```
     extension NSMutableAttributedString {

     func setColorForText(textForAttribute: String, withColor color: UIColor) {
        let range: NSRange = self.mutableString.range(of: textForAttribute, options: .caseInsensitive)
        self.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: color, range: range)

    }




         let stringValue = "Natural air is most important part of human body. people got too much problem because of it. please everybody try to do best part for it"


        let attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: stringValue)
        attributedString.setColorForText(textForAttribute: "\(item.catName ?? "")", withColor: Colors.green)

        postInfoLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: ViewSize.width/33)
       postInfoLabel.numberOfLines = 0
           postInfoLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

Comment: numberOfLines = 0 means any number of lines.

Comment: So you want to display the text in a label in multiple lines but you got only one?

Comment: i used numberOfLines = 0. the string supposed to show to two or three line. but it show just one line

Comment: bazyli7 is right. you are right friend. bazyl87

Comment: Check if you have you applied proper constraints to the label?

Comment: `.numberOfLines = 0` allows to use multiple lines (not showing "..." for instance), BUT it doesn't mean that the size of the label is enough. It depends then on your UI constraints/size.

Answer (score 0):

The technique to use for wrapping and truncating the label’s text is to set lineBreakMode property value to NSLineBreakByWordWrapping or NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail on the basis of your use case. This should work for you when you are setting the numberOfLines property to 0 for UILabel.

Answer (score 0):

`numberOfLines` is not a function but a property that indicates how many lines should `UILabel` display. If you set this value to `0` you are telling label to use as many lines as needed, to display text. You can read more details in [numberOfLines documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620539-numberoflines).

I'm not quite sure what do you want to achieve by setting font size as `ViewSize.width/33`, maybe there is an issue (like ViewSize is not calculated properly). Could you explain in more details what do you want to achieve, and what you get instead?

Comment: ViewSize.width = self.view.frame.size.width

Comment: but a view frame could be not set if you use it in `viewDidLoad`